# Enable PUT verb to certain areas of a ASP.NET MVC site only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, put, http-verbs

I'm enabling the PUT verb on my site with the following lines in web.config

```
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /> 
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
```

However, I only really want this to be applied to our /admin Area. How can I choose to apply this config to a specific area only? I have tried to add a new web.config in the area folder but haven't been successful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply configuration to specific directories or files using the `location` element as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
<configuration>
    <location path="admin">
        <!-- Configuration to apply to /admin goes here -->
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebDAV" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" /> 
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DEBUG,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>
        </<system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```